# dovecot replication duplicates

Tags: dovecot, replication

I got mailbox on both servers which are connected with eachother for dovecot replication. When mail comes to mailbox only on one server replication works ok, but when there is new mail on second server during replication I got this error:

```
dovecot: dsync-server(<<MAILBOX>>): Warning: Mailbox INBOX doesn't match previous state: Unexpected GUID mismatch for UID=237805: 58703d2e76898b588d7a0000c278a7cb != 89545203226fed6a8a3cde4a98690e96(guid128, orig=89545203226fed6a8a3cde4a98690e96) (dsync must be run again without the state)
```

and as a result i got this mail replicated in 2-3 copies on both sides.

Any ideas why?

my replicator config:

```
service replicator {
  process_min_avail = 1

  unix_listener replicator-doveadm {
    mode = 0660
    group = vmail
  }
}

service aggregator {
  fifo_listener replication-notify-fifo {
    user = vmail
  }
  unix_listener replication-notify {
    user = vmail
  }
}

service doveadm {
  inet_listener {
    port = 8999
    ssl = yes
  }
}

service config {
  unix_listener config {
    user = vmail
  }
}
```

plugins.conf

```
...
mail_replica = tcps:HOST_ONE
replication_max_conns = 1
#  replication_sync_timeout = 2s
replication_dsync_parameters = -d -N -l 30 -U
...
```

same config is on both servers (besides of *mail_replica* which is set for every host to point another one)

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you manage to find a solution?

Comment: unfortunately not. problem existed until I've turned off secondary machine and disabled replication.

Comment: Oh I see. I think I managed to fix it, but I'm not sure exactly what helped: I did disable the outlook workarounds, enabled optimized fsync instead of using never and updated the plugins list so that it's the same for deliver and imap. After that I haven't had any issues.

Comment: Have different hostnames been set for the machines?